# I got a TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: numpy, typeerror

I got the below error message. I have found some questions on Stack Overflow, and I tried their solutions but it didn't worked.

```
import numpy as np

R=0.9999 #Reflectivity

a=np.arange(0,100000,1,dtype=np.complex)
b=R**(a)
c=np.exp(np.complex(0,a))
```

Error:

> c=np.exp(np.complex(0,a))
>
> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in np.complex(0,a). It doesn't expect 'a' to be an array. Compare with:

```
c = np.exp(np.complex(0,a[0])).
```

Since a is already an array with complex numbers, can't you directly calculate it? (Although this will result in inf+0.j given the size of the exponent)

```
c = np.exp(a)
```

Comment: I would like to make 'c' to be a new array like 'b'. Of course, I can calculate suggested your codes.

Comment: c = np.exp(a) returns a array, same length as b :)